# Connection testing of DMS target endpoint fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dms

In my case, the source is SQL Server in EC2. Target is SQL Server in RDS.
In DMS, I created the replication instance. The source endpoint test is a success. But the target endpoint test fails with this error:

*Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Cannot connect to SQL Server  Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 42000 NativeError: 4060 Message: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Students" requested by the login. The login failed.*

Here Students is the source database I want to replicate. The error message is **Can not open database "Students" requested by the login**. What does it mean?